# Best approach to get ipv4 last octet

Tags: c#, ip-address

I know substring can handle this but, is there a better way to get last octet from an IP ?

Ex.:
192.168.1.100

I want 100

Tks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

just for fun:

```
Console.WriteLine(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.33").GetAddressBytes()[3]);
```

Comment: This *is* the way to do it by-the-book.

Comment: shouldn't you rather get the last byte by index? `var bytes = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.33").GetAddressBytes(); var value = bytes[bytes.Length - 1];` This would make it IPv6 etc. compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun I wrote the version which would have the least overhead (string manipulation etc.). [@rushui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927470/best-approach-to-get-ipv4-last-octet/6927593#6927593) has the correct answer though.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(OctetInIP("10.1.1.100", 0));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static byte OctetInIP(string ip, int octet)
{
    var octCount = 0;
    var result = 0;

    // Loop through each character.
    for (var i = 0; i < ip.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = ip[i];

        // If we hit a full stop.
        if (c == '.')
        {
            // Return the value if we are on the correct octet.
            if (octCount == octet)
                return (byte)result;
            octCount++;
        }
        else if (octCount == octet)
        {
            // Convert the current octet to a number.
            result *= 10;
            switch (c)
            {
                case '0': break;
                case '1': result += 1; break;
                case '2': result += 2; break;
                case '3': result += 3; break;
                case '4': result += 4; break;
                case '5': result += 5; break;
                case '6': result += 6; break;
                case '7': result += 7; break;
                case '8': result += 8; break;
                case '9': result += 9; break;
                default:
                    throw new FormatException();
            }

            if (result > 255)
                throw new FormatException();
        }
    }

    if (octCount != octet)
        throw new FormatException();

    return (byte)result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It may be overkill, but a simple regex would also do the trick:

```
(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})
```

Comment: This seems too much for a simple problem.

Answer (score -1):

Remember what an IP address is, it is a 32-bit (4 byte) number. So masking the address with the subnet mask would actually be the correct way to do it. If you always want a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, as your question implies, you can & the number with 0xFF to get the number.

But, if you don't care about efficiency, and only have the address as a string, the split on "." is just fine... :)